To implement the functionality when clicking the "End Call" button in mobile app

To implement the functionality when clicking the "End Call" button then i need response backe in flutter app, not clicked on any other event, without triger like this events _endPhoneCallData
    _endPhoneCallData() async {
          try {
            final callState;
           callState = await platform.invokeMethod('endCall');
           print('audio call ${callState}');
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print("Failed to end call: '${e.message}'.");
        }
            }

